# How to switch focus between my WPF application and the second window

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, user32

I am having a WPF application which is using for some element capturing purposes. So it is really important to switch the focus between applications. The application is working in a way that whenever I do a Ctrl KeyDown the focused element will capture and show it in my WPF window. Now the issue is if I click on the WPF application the focus is not switching to any other window unless I click the other window. Actually I need to focus on the very next window behind my WPF window whenever I move the mouse cursor from my window. How I can achieve this particular scenario.

I know user32 we can use to switch focuses, but how I will find the very next window or the second window and switch focus whenever I move my cursor from my WPF application(currently it have the focus).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a window of your application to get focus, when the user moves the mouse over a window of your application, then you can do that by setting a handler on the MouseEnter event on each window in your application, that you want to get focus, when the mouse moves over it:

```
  public YourWindow() : base()
  {

     // Other constructor code

     this.MouseEnter += this.windowMouseEnter;
  }

  private void windowMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     if (!e.Handled) this.Focus();
  }
```

Comment: not exactly the same, but whenever I move my cursor from my WPF application, I need to focus the window just behind my app. For example, if a chrome browser is just behind my window, on a mouse move, I have to focus the chrome window(the page opened exactly)

Comment: So your wish is not on windows in your application, but windows from other applications. Yes, that is something else ...